# new objects added during long loop

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, entity

We currently have a production application that runs as a windows service. Many times this application will end up in a loop that can take several hours to complete. We are using Entity Framework for .net 4.0 for our data access.

I'm looking for confirmation that if we load new data into the system, after this loop is initialized, it will not result in items being added to the loop itself. When the loop is initialized we are looking for data "as of" that moment. Although I'm relatively certain that this will work exactly like using ADO and doing a loop on the data (the loop only cycles through data that was present at the time of initialization), I am looking for confirmation for co-workers.

Thanks in advance for your help.

//update : here's some sample code in c# - question is the same, will the enumeration change if new items are added to the table that EF is querying?

```
IEnumerable<myobject> myobjects = (from o in db.theobjects where o.id==myID select o);
foreach (myobject obj in myobjects)
{
    //perform action on obj here
}
```

Comment: Jeff, you couldn't say with any certainty, it depends on how the code was written, not the framework.  Most (not all) programmers write batch processes to query all data at the beginning of the process.  However it's possible (though unlikely) that the program queries the database throughout the operation.  A definitive answer requires going through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your precise implementation.

Once a query has been executed against the database then the results of the query will not change (assuming you aren't using lazy loading).  To ensure this you can dispose of the context after retrieving query results--this effectively "cuts the cord" between the retrieved data and that database.

Lazy loading can result in a mix of "initial" and "new" data; however once the data has been retrieved it will become a fixed snapshot and not susceptible to updates.

You mention this is a long running process; which implies that there may be a very large amount of data involved.  If you aren't able to fully retrieve all data to be processed (due to memory limitations, or other bottlenecks) then you likely can't ensure that you are working against the original data.  The results are not fixed until a query is executed, and any updates prior to query execution will appear in results.

Comment: This was the answer, I need to see if implementing IEnumerable does the same thing as doing ToList(). Since lazy loading is on by default in EF

Comment: I also found confirmation that implementing IEnumerable eliminates the lazy loading piece and loads the results into memory. So the answer is that, with the code I have above the collection will stay intact.

Comment: yes, as a rule of thumb `IQueryable` is the interface you need to be most careful with

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a snapshot of ID's to be processed -- quickly and as a transaction -- then work that list in the fashion you're doing today.

In addition to accomplishing the goal of not changing the sample mid-stream, this also gives you the ability to extend your solution to track status on each item as it's processed.  For a long-running process, this can be very helpful for progress reporting restart / retry capabilities, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to change the logic of your application such that when the "loop" logic is determining whether it should do another interation or exit you take the opportunity to load the newly added items to the list.  see pseudo code below:

```
var repo = new Repository();
while (repo.HasMoreItemsToProcess())
{
   var entity = repo.GetNextItem();
}
```

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Hi thanks for that suggestion, but my concern is that I don't want the  new objects to be processed. Your code would be perfect if I needed to check for new objects and then insert them. The problem is I'm not sure how Entity Framework works while looping through an enumeration. If it qualifies the collection on every loop, or if it simply maintains the collection as it was originally intialized.

Comment: gotcha.  it transforms anything you write in Linq into a SQL query, so I would imagine any time you execute a query against the context its not "listening" for new rows being added.

Comment: (that's why I suggested adding a layer of abstraction of your own beyond EF)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to assure that this happens - if the data itself isn't too big - is to convert the data you retrieve from the database to a List<>, e.g., something like this (pulled at random from my current project):

```
var sessionIds = room.Sessions.Select(s => s.SessionId).ToList();
```

And then iterate through the list, not through the IEnumerable<> that would otherwise be returned. Converting it to a list triggers the enumeration, and then throws all the results into memory.

If there's too much data to fit into memory, and you need to stick with an IEnumerable<>, then the answer to your question depends on various database and connection settings.